# DataService SaveChanges is not saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using DataServices with EntityFramework 6.

I am trying to call SaveChanges, but ObjectState is "Unchanged" instead of "Added".

I don't have problems with querying and retrieving data, but Insert or Update doesn't work for some reason, because ObjectState is not working.

Code:

```
public void AddCustomerNote(CustomerIssueModel data)
{
    if (data.CustomerNote != null)
    {
        CustomerNote cn = CustomerNote.CreateCustomerNote(0, "test", 1, false, false, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, data.CustomerNote.CustomerId);
        ClientRepositories.LiveData.AddToCustomerNotes(cn);
        ClientRepositories.LiveData.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Where LiveData is DbContext via data service.

I am using generic EF6 UOW Repository Pattern from https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/

The thing is that the state is "unchanged" in SyncObjectStatePreCommit() and SyncObjectStatePostCommit():

```
                public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            SyncObjectsStatePreCommit();
            var changes = base.SaveChanges();
            SyncObjectsStatePostCommit();
            return changes;
        }

private void SyncObjectsStatePreCommit()
        {
            foreach (var dbEntityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                dbEntityEntry.State = StateHelper.ConvertState(((IObjectState)dbEntityEntry.Entity).ObjectState);
            }
        }

        public void SyncObjectsStatePostCommit()
        {
            foreach (var dbEntityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                ((IObjectState)dbEntityEntry.Entity).ObjectState = StateHelper.ConvertState(dbEntityEntry.State);
            }
        }
```

If I manually(debug) change state to "Added" from "Unchanged" it adds record to database.

I spent 2 days on this, still don't see what could be the issue.

Comment: see what actually happens in SyncObjectsStatePreCommit, I could imagine it sets the state on any entity in the ChangeTracker to Unchanged.

Comment: what is the code of `AddToCustomerNotes` ? sounds like you are attaching the entity and no adding it.

Comment: tschmit007, it adds entity to context, and than using SaveChanges to save. it is data services not direct context saving.